# Assigned data `geom` must be compatible with existing data

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple map of the total number of collisions by county. I will pool the collision across species and then make the fill color dependent on the number of collisions per 1,000 residents.
This formula is used for collisions scaled:

`collisions_scaled= (n_collisions × 1000)/ population`

Here is the code I have tried

```
df %>% 
 st_as_sf() %>%  
  group_by(county_id, species) %>% 
  summarise(
    n_collisions = n(), 
    collisions_scaled = (n_collisions * 1000)/county_population_2020,
    .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = wildlife_collisions,
          aes(fill = collisions_scaled)) +
  theme_void()
```

but I kept getting this error message:

> Error:
> ! Assigned data `geom` must be compatible with existing data.
> x Existing data has 40015 rows.
> x Assigned data has 505 rows.
> i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Where am I missing something? What is wrong with my code? I have been on this for over 3 hours. Note that I have used this in a previous way and it worked. Here is the way I used it.

```
df %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  group_by(county_id, species) %>% 
  summarise(
    total = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = species)) +
  theme_void()
```

Comment: In your `geom_sf`, you're using variable *collisions_scaled* of dataframe **df** for the dataframe **wildlife_collisions** apparently defined elsewhere. The error message suggests both dataframes are of different size (row count).

Comment: Sorry, wildlife-collisions is the same as the dataframe, df. I changed the object name to df while posting the question. I forgot to change the one at geom_sf to df. Thanks. I am still hoping for a way to solve this error.

Comment: Strange. Does using planar instead of spherical geometry help: `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` ? See discussion of this issue on the {sf} package repo: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1881